# Type Script Decorators for Authorization in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am developing server side nodejs application using typescript.I have to implement authorization in my nodejs application. I was planning to use Type script "Method and Class Decorators" for the same.But below post states, "Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future releases". 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Can someone please suggest, what is the best cleaner way to implement authorization?

If I go with decorators, How much will future VSCode releases impact its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO using decorators is fine. TypeScript will not drop them and there is also a [TC39 proposal for them](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/) (currently stage 2).

If you're using the power of the internet, I am sure you'll find plenty of example that use decorators to do authentication. A quick search gave me this express lib: https://github.com/Romakita/ts-express-decorators

But you do not need to limit your search to TypeScript. People, who are using Babel, are also already using decorators.

---

*Not quite sure what your editor (VSCode) has to do with this language feature.*